# Removing part of the file names

Tags: regex, linux, bash, redhat, file-rename

I have a bunch of files like this:

```
file123.txt.452
file456.txt.098
file789.txt.078
```

How can I remove the second dot and the numbers at the end from the file names?

I tried using `rename` but I don’t think my regex is correct:

```
rename 's/txt.*/txt/' *
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
for f in *.txt.*; do
    g=${f%.txt.*}.txt
    mv $f $g
done
```

Answer (score 6):

Try `rename 's/txt\..+/txt/' *`.

`\.` is for the literal dot and `.+` for anything after it.

The actual name of the command [depends on your system](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/275254/241621). It could be `rename`, `file-rename`, `perl-rename` or something else. The `rename` command that the above code works with has this in its `man` entry:

```
NAME
       rename - renames multiple files

SYNOPSIS
       rename [-bfilnv] [-B prefix] [-S suffix] [-V method] [-Y prefix] [-z suffix]
       [--backup] [--basename-prefix=prefix] [--dry-run] [--force] [--help] [--no-stdin]
       [--interactive] [--just-print] [--link-only] [--prefix=prefix] [--suffix=suffix]
       [--verbose] [--version-control=method] [--version] perlexpr [files]...

DESCRIPTION
       rename renames the filenames supplied according to the rule specified as the first
       argument.  The argument is a Perl expression which is expected to modify the $_ string
       for at least some of the filenames specified.  If a given filename is not modified by
       the expression, it will not be renamed.  If no filenames are given on the command
       line, filenames will be read via standard input.
```

Comment: By the way, thanks to this question I’ve learned about the existence and usage of the `rename` command today. This will probably be useful for me as well…

Comment: I tried that regex but it didn't work either. perhaps my syntax is wrong

Comment: That’s weird. I tried exactly the same as your example with these file names (“file123.txt.456”) and applied that command and it worked perfectly…

Comment: may be perl isnt installed properly on my machine. Rename is part of the perl package.

Answer (score -1):

Try a regex like this:

```
string.replace("(.+\\.txt)(.+)", "$1")
```

Comment: which programming language is that in? please make sure it will work from the terminal too